# WooCommerce & Gravity Forms: add to cart on radio label selection

Tags: woocommerce

Thanks in advance for the help!

I have a WooCommerce product that I turned into a donation form via the Gravity Forms WooCommerce add-on.

The goal here is to have a one-page process for the donation form --where all the fields, billing information and credit card information is collected all on one page.

The One Page Checkout WooCommerce extension has helped a lot in doing this, but the form is still not perfect: https://dev.sanma.org/sponsor-a-project/

What I want to do is remove the "Add to cart" button all together and make it so that when people select a price, it will trigger that amount to be added to the cart.

I think the following code is close, but I can't get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
    $('#input_4_2 input').on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

The code above triggers the checkout itself, not the add to cart button.

Can you help with this?

Thanks mucho,
Roselle